# Can I upgrade the OS of a vm in azure?

Tags: azure, operating-system, virtual-machine, upgrade

I want to know if there is a way to upgrade from windows server 2012 to windows server 2016 in a vm in Azure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no way to upgrade Windows server in place.  You can only do this with a Windows 10 VM.  There are two work-arounds available.

1. Create an Azure VM that runs a supported version of the operating system, and then migrate the workload.
2. Download the VHD to a locally running HyperV instance, upgrade, upload to Azure.

Full details on the workarounds can be found here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/in-place-system-upgrade